# How do I check if all the elements of a nested list tree are identical?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I am trying to create a function `allsametree(tree)` that takes a list, `tree`, as an input and returns TRUE or FALSE if all the elements of the list are numerically identical. So far, I have the following function:

```
def allsametree(tree):
    if not type(tree) == list:
        return tree
    if type(tree) is list:
        final_lst = []
        for item in tree:
            final_lst.append(allsametree(item))
        return final_lst[1:] == final_lst[:-1]
```

While for the most part, this function works, it runs into an issue when evaluating `allsametree([1, [[[[[2]]]]]])`

Any tips, or alternative ways you would approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can recursively convert the list to a set of items and return true if the length of the overall set is 1:

```
def allsametree(tree):
    def to_set(tree):
        if isinstance(tree, list):
            return {item for obj in tree for item in to_set(obj)}
        return {tree}
    return len(to_set(tree)) == 1
```

Comment: While this addresses the case listed above, I am also concerned about evaluating empty lists `[]`. This method would overlook empty lists and return false since the `len([])` would be 0 instead of 1. I appreciate your help nonetheless.

Comment: The OP does not specify what to return with an empty list, but from the wording of "all items are identical" I interpret it as the list needing to have something at all to be considered having identical items. Otherwise, it's easy to change `== 1` to `<= 1`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and it certainly makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it. Split it into two operations a flatten and a check that all the values are the same.

The flatten will convert a nested iterable into one of a single dimension. So `[1, [[[[[2]]]]]]` becomes `[1,2]`.

Then read the first value and cycle through the rest to check they are the same as it.

Here's the code

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

def flatten(iterable):
    for i in iterable:
        if isinstance(i, Iterable):
            yield from flatten(i)
        else:
            yield i


def allsametree(tree):
    flat = flatten(tree)
    iterator = iter(flat)
    try:
        first = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        return True
    return all(first == rest for rest in iterator)
```

This will work for any `iterable` not just lists and because it uses lazy evaluation, it will stop when it finds two values that are not equal. This saves you from doing unnecessary work. It also avoid instantiating temporary collections (lists, sets etc.) being constructed on each recursive call.

[Here's](https://repl.it/repls/MediumpurpleExcitingTransversals#main.py) a few test inputs.

Comment: This is very insightful, I haven't thought of this. Thank you!